# How to I join two tables with two required parameters and one optional parameter?

Tags: mysql, sql

I apologize if this is fairly basic MySQL, but I'm at a loss. I have two tables: `users` and `us_geolocations` and I would like to create a View of the geolocations of the users.

My first issue is that I have multiple `lat` and `long` entries for some cities (and even some zip codes) in my `us_geolocations`. And my second issue is that I have `zip` as an optional parameter in my `users` table.

What I would like is to have a View with all distinct `city`, `state`, `zip`, `lat` and `long` values, where the `city` and `state` are in the `users` table.

What I have now is:

```
CREATE VIEW `active_us_geolocations` AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        `users`.`city` AS `city`,
        `users`.`state` AS `state`,
        `users`.`zip` AS `zip`,
        `us_geolocations`.`lat` AS `lat`,
        `us_geolocations`.`long` AS `long`
    FROM
        (`users`
        LEFT JOIN `us_geolocations` 
            ON (((`users`.`city` = `us_geolocations`.`city`)
            AND (`users`.`state` = `us_geolocations`.`state`)

            #Only if there is a `users`.`zip`
            AND (`users`.`zip` = `us_geolocations`.`zip`))))
```

But when the `zip` is empty in `users`, I also get empty `lat` and `long`.

Do I need to separate the required parameters and optional parameters into their own queries, or is it possible to do them in a specific type of join? And if it does need to be in separate sections, how would I go about designating that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
CREATE VIEW `active_us_geolocations` AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        `users`.`city`           AS `city`,
        `users`.`state`          AS `state`,
        `users`.`zip`            AS `zip`,
        `us_geolocations`.`lat`  AS `lat`,
        `us_geolocations`.`long` AS `long`
    FROM
        `users`
    LEFT JOIN
        `us_geolocations`
    ON
             `users`.`city`  = `us_geolocations`.`city`
        AND  `users`.`state` = `us_geolocations`.`state`
        AND (`users`.`zip`   = `us_geolocations`.`zip`
        OR   `users`.`zip` IS NULL
        OR   `users`.`zip = '')
```

**Edit:**

The solution above selects all active city/state/zip/lat/long combinations by matching user addresses with lat/long values by making sure that the city and state match, and then also checking the zip if it is present.

Perhaps instead you wish to match user addresses with lat/long values if either the city and state match *or* the zip matches. This is a slightly different query, shown here:

```
CREATE VIEW `active_us_geolocations` AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        `users`.`city`           AS `city`,
        `users`.`state`          AS `state`,
        `users`.`zip`            AS `zip`,
        `us_geolocations`.`lat`  AS `lat`,
        `us_geolocations`.`long` AS `long`
    FROM
        `users`
    LEFT JOIN
        `us_geolocations`
    ON
            `users`.`city`  = `us_geolocations`.`city`
        AND `users`.`state` = `us_geolocations`.`state`
        OR  `users`.`zip`   = `us_geolocations`.`zip`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE VIEW `active_us_geolocations` AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        `users`.`city` AS `city`,
        `users`.`state` AS `state`,
        `users`.`zip` AS `zip`,
        `us_geolocations`.`lat` AS `lat`,
        `us_geolocations`.`long` AS `long`
    FROM
        (`users`
        LEFT JOIN `us_geolocations` 
            ON (((`users`.`city` = `us_geolocations`.`city`)
            AND (`users`.`state` = `us_geolocations`.`state`)
WHERE `users`.`zip` IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have some good answers in SQL code, given your SQL structures (I haven't tried any of them so just saying that at a glance & without knowing for sure what your data structures are like, they look good).

You might also consider one of two alternate solutions/thoughts:

1. If you are the one writing the database code/creating the database structure you might consider a higher level of normalization. This should make the separation of comparison of different pieces of data a bit more clean.
   What I mean is instead of having the zip code values in both tables have them in one table then create a linkage table between them (normalization, boiled down, largely amounts to not duplicating data). 

   This makes the relational part of RDBMS easier as the underlying math depends on uniqueness of data, so the more unique the more effectively your data relations can be enforced by the database system.
2. If this query is in support of an application you could, consider putting the conditional components of the query on the application side and making the view a more general structure, (though if your database structures where more normalized a left join would still most likely take care of what is causing you problems).

Hope that helps, but just in case here are a couple links regarding [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) & [surrogate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).

**Also, more details on point 1:**

In this way you would have more than 2 tables to hold the data. In fact if this were a database I created I would create a locations table (or group of tables, remembering to attempt to avoid duplication of each piece as much as is reasonable) and a linkage to a [geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation), since you are using latitude & longitude as geolocation... and depending on how specific the lat & long are (if, for instance, your latitudinal and longitudinal coordinates could encompass more than one address).
In the event that you are keeping track of coordinates that are so exact that one coordinate represents one address, then the address table and geolocation table should be the same table. While a city should be held in it's own table.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
...
LEFT JOIN `us_geolocations` 
  ON users.city=us_geolocations.city
    AND users.state=us_geolocations.state
    AND (users.zip IS NULL OR users.zip=us_geolocations.zip)
```